# Git: Add only a specific set of wildcards and ignore everything else

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm working on a project and I want to ignore everything that is not `.cpp`, `.h`, `.cxx` and `.hpp` files for example. How can I do that? I tried adding the following lines to my `.gitignore` file but it still adds libs and png files and other junk:

```
!*.cpp
!*.h
!*.hpp
!*.hxx
!*.cxx
!*.c
```

How can I ignore everything but these extensions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
*.*
```

at the beginning of your .gitignore file.

That will ignore every file except the ones that you defined below with a '!'.

You can find a lot of useful .gitignore file on [Github](https://github.com/github/gitignore) or on [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io/)